# Postgresql rounding to significant figures

Tags: postgresql, math, postgresql-9.6, significant-digits

i've tried this significant figures query from this blog (https://www.garysieling.com/blog/postgres-significant-figures-pg_size_pretty).

But it seems have fixed decimal digit on it.

```
SELECT FLOOR(5.4321/(10 ^ FLOOR(log(5.4321)-1))) * (10 ^ FLOOR(log(5.4321)-1))
```

The result from the query above is 5.4.
How can i achieve query to create these results?

```
number | sigfig
5.4321 | 5.43
10.987 | 10.9
550.75 | 550
9850.5 | 9850
ect
```

Thank you for you help brothers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following function to round to a number of significant digits:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sig_digits(n anyelement, digits int) 
RETURNS numeric
AS $$
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN n=0 THEN 0
        ELSE round(n, digits - 1 - floor(log(abs(n)))::int)
    END
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Compared to Laurenz' answer this has the following differences:

- the results are rounded, not floored (e.g. `sig_digits(15, 1)` is `20`, not `10`)
- the function takes arbitrary types as first argument (like floats), not only numerics
- it's faster, because it avoids calling `log` on numeric (which is slow) if possible and only calls `log` once
- it returns pretty results without an unnecessary amount of trailing zeros.
- it handles zero inputs

Comment: You should use `floor(log(abs(n)))` so negatives numbers works too.

Comment: select case when n is null then null
    when n = 0 then 0
    else round(n, digits - 1 - floor(log(abs(n)))::int) end;

Comment: @AdamGering I added handling for the zero case. Nulls work without extra changes in my tests, so I didn't add an extra case for that.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a more general answer to this question, I suggest that you use the following function where the number of significant digits is variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION significant_digits(n numeric, digits integer) RETURNS numeric
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
'SELECT floor(n / (10 ^ floor(log(n) - digits + 1)))
        * (10 ^ floor(log(n) - digits + 1))';
```

Then you get the following:

```
test=> SELECT significant_digits(5.4321, 3);
 significant_digits 
--------------------
 5.4300000000000000
(1 row)

test=> SELECT significant_digits(9.87654, 3);
 significant_digits 
--------------------
 9.8700000000000000
(1 row)
```

Note that the formula does not *round* as the blog post claims, but *truncate*.

Comment: wow, thank you brother, but how can i get just the important number only, without the zeros?
5.4300000000000000 -> 5.43

Comment: Cast to `text` and apply `trim(trailing '0' from ...)` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Example of rounding count(status) to Most significant digit:

```
select count(status),
  round(count(status) / pow(10, trunc(log(count(status))) ) ) * pow(10, trunc(log(count(status))) ) 
  from  some_table;

Eg. 1234 => 1000
    987  => 900
```